# does anyone know how to transform this query from mongo to mongo template?

Tags: spring, mongodb, mongotemplate

what i want to do is first transform this query to mongo template

```
db.project.aggregate([
   {
      $project: {      
          boos:1,
          "errors":{
            $cond: {
               if: { $eq : [ 3,"$error.status" ] },
               then: '$$REMOVE',
               else: "$error"
            }
          }
      }
   }
])
```

the goal is to bring all the projects and errors, however to show the errors as null or blank if their status is 3

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to find all the projects whose status is 3:

```
Query query = new Query(); 
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("status").is(3));
List<Project> projects = mongoTemplate.find(query, "project");
```

Comment: I can't because I need to show the information of the projects with their errors but not show if their status is 3